# Covariance/contravariance: how to make the following code compile

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, covariance

**UPDATE:** The following code only makes sense in C#4.0 (Visual Studio 2010)

It seems like I am having some misunderstanding of covariance/contravariance thing. Can anybody tell me why the following code doesn't compile?

```
public class TestOne<TBase>
{
    public IEnumerable<TBase> Method<TDerived>(IEnumerable<TDerived> values)
        where TDerived: TBase
    {
        return values;
    }
}
```

while this one compiles: (!!!)

```
public interface IBase
{
}
public interface IDerived: IBase
{
}
public class TestTwo
{
    public IEnumerable<IBase> Method(IEnumerable<IDerived> values)
    {
        return values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Covariance only applies to reference types (for the type arguments), so you have to add a class constraint:

```
public IEnumerable<TBase> Method<TDerived>(IEnumerable<TDerived> values)
    where TDerived : class, TBase
{
    return values;
}
```

This will prevent you from trying to convert, say, an `IEnumerable<int>` into an `IEnumerable<object>`, which is invalid.

Comment: @Adam : I believe you are wrong, `IEnumerable<ISuper>` is not `IEnumerable<IBase>` by default so it wouldn't compile even in `3.5`

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: No, that code *wouldn't* have compiled before .NET 4. I've just tried it myself to verify that. Without generic invariance, the conversion from `IEnumerable<ISuper>` to `IEnumerable<IBase>` is simply invalid.

Comment: @bonomo: Okay, fixed my answer in line with the question change :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of any situation where you actually need `TDerived`. Using `TBase` is sufficient:

```
public class TestOne<TBase>
{
    public IEnumerable<TBase> Method(IEnumerable<TBase> values)
    {
        return values;
    }
}
```

After all, you have no information about `TDerived` apart from the fact that it is a `TBase`...

Comment: unfortunately it is not something I made up for the sake of complexity, it's a real situation that I ended up having in my code

Comment: @bonomo: That's interesting, I would love to see a more detailed example for future reference. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Neither compiled for me initially.  Both failed on the implicit cast from Super(T/I) to Base(T/I).  When I added an explicit case, however, both compiled.

```
public IEnumerable<TBase> Method<TSuper>(IEnumerable<TSuper> values)
    where TSuper: TBase
    {
        return (IEnumerable<TBase>) values;
    }
```